# Android App taking up a lot of memory

Tags: java, android, memory-management

While working on my Android application, I recently check a task manager to see how memory my application is racking up.

Right now my application has two ad banners being executed by AdMob services and then an interface fragment for a Google Map. Aside from all that I then have a menu in which I utilize a container to which I add views to it in Java code. I prefer this over a list-view as it is more light weight and easier for me to structure what I want to do with the views (and I can use Androids native animation system when adding/removing the views).

The views being added to the container are being added by a loop structure based on conditions. The views in their interface structure also have a small image-view utilizing a small local drawable.

All of this is somehow adding up to my application 44.8 MB in memory which seems abnormally high from previous development numbers. This is also the first time I decided to use the container to add views through a loop rather then the adapter with list-view method.

Can anyone tell right off hand why my application is taking up so much memory right off? This is my first time utilizing all these components: AdMob Banners, Google Maps, and Containers with added Views.

My LogCat shows no warnings of doing anything inefficiently. Just curious to see if I am doing anything wrong. If anyone has any ideas I am open to provide any source code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think 44.8Mb is pretty normal for a modern Android application. My bet is on Google Maps since it's very resource-consuming library (both CPU-wise and memory-wise). Anyway, you can try to sequentially remove each of the component out of app and see how it affects memory footprint.

Comment: Thanks Andrey! I guess I'm just on edge as I still have to implement a service which will collect about 13 small icons to still implement in the app. For some reason I remember reading that applications cannot extend past 64 MB but I may be wrong. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't pushing that boundary. I will try removing each component to see if anything resolves. Thanks again.

Comment: 64Mb is still a normal memory usage for an app. You can use [getMemoryClass](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getMemoryClass()) method to get an idea what's the limit on a particular device. Ignore the documentation which mentions 16Mb, my app shows that 96Mb is the most popular memory class across different devices (~30k devices running Android 3.0+).

Answer (score 5):

As Andrey have already said, 44.8Mb is not too much for an Android application. But you can use DDMS to track allocations and heap updates to see exactly is taking up this memory. See this: https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html

Besides, I would recommend using a `ListView` with adapter because items in `ListView` can be recycled, which can improve performance considerablly (See [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#listsactivity_performance) tutorial).

Comment: I did not know about this tool! I will have to utilize this. I am kind of a reverse engineer kind of guy so always learning these new tools is always useful! Thanks Rafi!